# JS touch event pendant to click

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Is `touchstart` the pendant to click?

If yes, what is it for `mousedown`? If not what is it then for `click`?

```
mousedown = touchstart
click = ?
mouseup = touchend
```

or

```
mousedown = ?
click = touchstart
mouseup = touchend
```

Are `mousedown` and similar events consistently triggered on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the click is `mousedown` -> keep focus on element -> `mouseup` (`click` is dispatched together with `mouseup`.

The same applies to `touchstart` and `touchend`, `click` is dispatched with `touchend`.

Look at following example to get thing clearer:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="test">test</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
        console.log("down");
      });
      document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("click");
      });
      document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        console.log("up");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You click and hold on `test` button, you'll see in your console `down`. Now you release your mouse and you'll see both `click` and `up`.

If you click and hold, then you move your pointer away before releasing, you won't see neither `click` nor `up`.

Be aware that long time between `touchstart` and `touchend` dispatch a `contextmenu` (right click) instead of just `click`.

Comment: You mean mousedown and holding is triggering click after a while? So the pendant would be touchevent (more or less)?

Comment: I should stop aswering on morning before coffee. I corrected some typos and provided an example. Let me know if it is now clear.

Comment: Yea your answer has improved massively after your second iteration :P this behaviour was kind of obvious ... i should stop asking question without coffee ;)